# Git not in PATH for Homebrew on Mac

Tags: git, homebrew

A couple days ago, I ran `brew update`, trying to update homebrew on my Mac (I use OSX 10.9.5). When I ran this, I got this back

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/git/bin/git
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh: line 193: 25509 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/git/bin/git" --version > /dev/null
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/git/bin/git
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh: line 193: 25615 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/git/bin/git" --version > /dev/null
Warning: curl 7.63.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link curl` to link this version.
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/git/bin/git
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh: line 193: 25750 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/git/bin/git" --version > /dev/null
Warning: git 2.20.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.20.1, run `brew reinstall git`
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!
```

I also ran brew doctor, to see if anything had changed. This is what came up.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/git/bin/git
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh: line 193: 25891 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/git/bin/git" --version > /dev/null
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/curl-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/freetype-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/icu-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/krb5-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/libpng-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/libpng16-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/ncursesw6-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/pcre-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/python-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/python2-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/python2.7-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/xml2-config
  /Users/Robby/anaconda2/bin/xslt-config

Warning: Git could not be found in your PATH.
Homebrew uses Git for several internal functions, and some formulae use Git
checkouts instead of stable tarballs. You may want to install Git:
  brew install git

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  autoconf
  automake
  bash-completion
  brotli
  c-ares
  cask
  cmake
  cunit
  docbook
  docbook-xsl
  doxygen
  emacs
  fontconfig
  freetype
  gdbm
  geoip
  gmp
  gnutls
  htop
  itstool
  jansson
  jemalloc
  jpeg
  libev
  libevent
  libpng
  libtasn1
  libtool
  libunistring
  nettle
  nmap
  p11-kit
  pcre2
  pkg-config
  python@2
  watch

Warning: You are using macOS 10.9.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures and other breakages.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on
Homebrew's GitHub, Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are
responsible for resolving any issues you experience, as
you are running this old version.


Warning: Some installed formulae are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install python

Run `brew missing` for more details.
```

This is what came up when I ran `brew missing`.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/git/bin/git
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh: line 193: 26131 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/git/bin/git" --version > /dev/null
itstool: python
libxml2: python
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: I would first format your question so people can actually read it.

Comment: uh also, apart from hard to read, i'm not really sure what you want to achieve and what steps you have done to do so. `git` not in path can be solved by adding `git` into your path, do you have git? how did you install it? can your run `git --version` on your terminal..?

Comment: I want to be able to run brew update without the error of git not being in my PATH

Comment: I fixed it!!! I had to reinstall homebrew... but now it works!!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue while I was trying to install android-platforms-tools and I tried to reinstall pcre2 lib, which worked for me.

```
brew uninstall --force pcre2
```

followed by

```
brew install pcre2
```

Comment: Noice, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following (as adviced by `brew` in your output text):

```
brew reinstall git
```

or:

```
brew reinstall git && brew unlink git && brew link git
```

or:

```
brew upgrade git
```

Comment: Solution doesn't work.  I get this error: **dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/pcre2/lib/libpcre2-8.0.dylib**